# Laravel 5.1 is Admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a simple users table which I define and admin by having a 1 in the type column.

I have the following setup in my middleware but this still doesn't stop non admins accessing admin only areas.

Middleware:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Admin {

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Kernal:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'admin' => App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
];
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'admin'], function () {

Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
Route::get('admin/orders', 'AdminController@orders');

});
```

Function in my User class:

```
public function isAdmin()
    {

        if (Auth::user()->type == '1')
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass multiple middleware as an array:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']]
```